# Exporting to CSV files in Julia

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia, export-to-csv

Warning: these are noob questions, since I'm *really* new to Julia.

In R, there is quite an "unified" function to export (almost) any kind of object with `read.table()`. It looks like things are slightly more complicated in Julia. If I understand well:

1. Some standard types (e.g., arrays, dictionaries and tuples) can always be exported with `writedlm`, but not always with `CSV.write`. Conversely, DataFrames can always be exported with `CSV.write`, but never with `writedlm`. Is this correct? Thus, there is no "universal exporter", in a similar sense of R's `write.table()`?
2. Along with writing a CSV file, `CSV.write` also seems to return the name of the exported file. Conversely, `writedlm` does not. This is a problem for me. Actually, I would need a way to export a DataFrame into a CSV file with a function which does *not* return a value, i.e. a function which only has side effects, like `writedlm`. Is there any way to achieve this in Julia?

   **EDIT**: To go into more details, my problem is that after a `CSV.write`, `ans` points towards the name of the exported file; and this is not the case with `writedlm`. An illustration [here](https://zupimages.net/up/20/41/1uxe.png) and [here](https://zupimages.net/up/20/41/w42e.png). Even with the idea given by @Przemyslaw Szufel, I can't get rid of this. (This is quite a subtle problem, but I'm actually trying to write a emacs lisp backend for Julia. This kind of inconsistencies, e.g. not knowing whether `ans` will be `nothing` or a filename after exporting an object, adds some more pain in this adventure... :-) Ideally, I just had wanted that `CSV.write` could be silent.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I start with the second question because it is short. Just use semicolon `;` at the end of line and no value will be returned!

```
CSV.write(file, table);
```

However if you want to be sure that `ans` has no value add `nothing` at the end:

```
CSV.write(file, table);nothing;
```

if you want you can pack it to a function:

```
function my_write(file, table)
    CSV.write(file, table)
    nothing
end
```

Or, if you want a one-liner wrap it into a lambda:

```
julia> (() -> begin;CSV.write("file.csv", df);nothing;end)()

julia> ans == nothing
true
```

In each case no side effect (returned value) will be observed.

The first question is more tricky. The possible formats used for storing data in a file obviously need to depend on the format of the data. Basically the most common options for Julia include (I start from the most generic ones and finish on the most specific ones):

- serialization via `serialize` command
- binary JSON via the `BSON.jl` package
- JSON via `JSON.jl` or slightly newer `JSON3.jl` package (both make a good choice as of today)
- `JSONTables.jl` for tabular data stored as JSON
- `DelimitedFiles` for storing `Array`s
- `CSV.jl` for storing `DataFrame`s

Now the choice of a particular package will depend on what is your objective. Serialization is the killer mechanism - fastest and most versatile. Any object can be stored this way in the shortest time possible. Nothing comes without the cost - when you update Julia version or your packages you might not be able to read your object back. So it is designed for short term storage.

In the middle of the stake are JSON-based storage systems. Basically, everything can be stored as JSON and can be read later in Julia or other programming languages. Text based JSON can be also opened in an simple text editor.

Finally, `CSV.jl` and `Serialization` can be used for tables and arrays respectively. However it is easy to convert a `DataFrame` to an `Array` or an `Array` to a `DataFrame`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=rand(3),c=["a","b","c"])
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b        │ c      │
│     │ Int64 │ Float64  │ String │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 0.440796 │ a      │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 0.44232  │ b      │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 0.282064 │ c      │

julia> Matrix(df)
3×3 Array{Any,2}:
 1  0.440796  "a"
 2  0.44232   "b"
 3  0.282064  "c"
```

You can see that the only thing lost in the process is the type information which does not matter so much if you are exporting the data via `DelimitedFiles`.

The conversion other way around is also straightforward:

```
julia> rand(3,3) |> Tables.table |> DataFrame
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Column1  │ Column2   │ Column3  │
│     │ Float64  │ Float64   │ Float64  │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.326649 │ 0.0278134 │ 0.111221 │
│ 2   │ 0.769378 │ 0.996156  │ 0.237821 │
│ 3   │ 0.802094 │ 0.726497  │ 0.619013 │
```

In conclusion, as you can see, everything can be done in Julia.

Comment: Many thanks for this great answer! My first question has now a perfect explanation, I've all I need now ;-) However, it seems that my second question is more tricky that I thought... I edited my original post with more details and examples.

Comment: Two small comments to this great answer: 1) CSV.jl is for tables in general - not only for `DataFrame`. 2) In general conversion of a matrix into a table should be done using `Tables.table` function (as different matrices specialize in a different way on how they expect to be handled as a table + `Tables.table` is non-allocating).